# R - Converting downloaded data frame to xts

Tags: r, xts

I am looking to chart the last 10 years of US GDP data. I usually source from Quandl but have had some problems with the data not updating on the site from the original source, hence I have gone to the original source.  I can get the data into R from a csv file OK, but I'm having trouble converting it to xts from which I can subset the data required.  I have tried various combinations of xts but all have come up with errors which I looked up but couldn't find a solution. Any help appreciated for converting the data to xts.

Initial code run from Tinn-R:

```
library(xts)

download.file("http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/data/GDPC96.csv",destfile="usgdp.csv")

x=read.csv("usgdp.csv", header=TRUE)
```

Data in 'x' (first 10 lines):

```
         DATE     VALUE
1   1947-01-01  1934.471

2   1947-04-01  1932.281

3   1947-07-01  1930.315

4   1947-10-01  1960.705

5   1948-01-01  1989.535

6   1948-04-01  2021.851

7   1948-07-01  2033.155

8   1948-10-01  2035.329

9   1949-01-01  2007.522

10  1949-04-01  2000.788
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass `xts` the data in the first argument and a time based index in the second:

```
xts(x$VALUE, as.Date(x$DATE))
```

---

It may have been easier to use quantmod to download the data from the same source.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GDPC96", src="FRED")
head(GDPC96)
#              GDPC96
# 1947-01-01 1934.471
# 1947-04-01 1932.281
# 1947-07-01 1930.315
# 1947-10-01 1960.705
# 1948-01-01 1989.535
# 1948-04-01 2021.851
```